# jQuery Hash History - No History

Tags: jquery, ajax, hash, history

I'm using [Ben Almon's Hash history plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), and it's all working perfect, except for when the back button is used to return to the homepage - which has no hash tag.

So I'm going from:
www.mysite.com/#category1 to www.mysite.com/ using the back button.

Although the browser changes, my page doesn't reload.

My code is pretty much the same as his example code. Although, if there is no hash tag in the URL, I just want to load exactly what is in the browser URL. At the moment it just does nothing.

Where the **????**'s are in my code below, I have tried putting in a line to redirect the URL to my homepage, but it keeps firing in an infinite loop, because the plugin reads that there is no #tag, so reloads the page again.

So the question is, what should go in the ??? below:

```
        $(document).ready(function() 
    {
       // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
      // hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.

      $(window).hashchange( function(){
        var hash = location.hash;
        var param=  ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'Blank' );

    if(param=='Blank'){ **?????**}

     else
     {
      // Set the page title based on the hash.
      document.title = ( param );

     //do other stuff 
     }
     });

      // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
      // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.

          $(window).hashchange();


});
```

Comment: can't you just load the homepage content in that location, like you do for all other pages?

Comment: I don't think so, I am using jquery .load() to get some content from another page and put it into a large content area on the home page

Comment: You say it gets into an infinite loop if you put a redirect there, so it is being called. Therefore, instead of a redirect, just put the code to load the homepage content, like you do in the else block for other pages. If that doesn't work, please explain what is going wrong exactly.

Comment: That may work, but I have a few pages that may be navigated back to in the same way as the homepage. THanks